# Multiple Process bar change the type

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in data.names">
       <td>
           <progressbar class="progress-striped"  value="data.value.marks"       
             type="dynamic value">{{ data.value.name }}</progressbar>
      </td>

</tr>
```

Need to change the type="data.value.type"  depends on value

change the type like -> warning, success, info

please guide me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like

```
<progressbar class="progress-striped"  value="data.value.marks"       
             type="{{getType(data.value)}}">{{ data.value.name }}</progressbar>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.getType = function(value){
// do some logic 
return type
}
```

Comment: Note : Return type should be of String